# How to Fix WordPress Website Performance Issue

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed-insights

I have a wordpress [website](https://getthattech.com/), it performance is poor according to [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgetthattech.com%2F). Please help me with it.

I have used plugins like Autotimize but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your HTML code and have the following advice you can start with that will net you big improvements:

- Combine and minify CSS and JS resources
- Minify your HTML and enable gzip to serve pages
- Use HTTP2
- Defer or Async JS
- Optimize images; Consider responsive images; Consider using webp format
- Consider using a CDN to serve resources

Appears that you're also pulling in many third-party scripts including an advertising platform. Ad services rarely care how well your site scores in tests and are not terribly inclined to serve up content quickly. Including them will always impact performance negatively.

Also, you'll never score 100 with a Wordpress website on Google metrics. Anything over 90 should be consider a success. I've been optimizing websites for marketing purposes for many years and have never gotten to 100. 99. But not 100.